# Type or Name Space error when using ImageGen

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, namespaces, web-config

I am using ImageGen for displaying images , I have added the ImageGen.ashx and added the config file of ImageGen plus added some settings on webconfig :

```
<configSections>
    <section name="ImageGenConfiguration" type="ImageGen.ImageGenConfigurationHandler,ImageGen" />
</configSections>
     <ImageGenConfiguration configSource="config\ImageGen.config" />
```

But when I try to compile it gives an error :

The type or namespace name 'ImageGen' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Ergo\ImageGen.ashx   12
The ImageGen.ashx is:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="c#" Class="RequestHandler" %>
```

public class RequestHandler : System.Web.IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

```
public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context)
{
    ImageGen.ImageGenQueryStringParser parser = new ImageGen.ImageGenQueryStringParser();
    parser.Process(context);
    parser = null;
}
```

}

Any advice or suggestion will be appreciated, Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you copy ImageGen.dll to your bin folder and referenced it in the project ?

Kris

Comment: So, do you have a source for ImageGen class ?

Answer (score 1):

ImageGen is made up of three files:

- imagegen.ashx
- /bin/imagegen.dll
- /config/imagegen.config (you can change the location of this file but be sure your web.config entry references its location)

If you're using Umbraco you can install ImageGen directly into your site with all files and settings from the Package Repository in Umbraco's Developer section. Or download the zip file (don't unzip it) and install the local package.

To use ImageGen in another site, you'll need to unzip the downloaded file and put the files in their proper places. The documentation describes how to do this.

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/imagegen has the download, docs, and dedicated forum for help.

cheers,

doug.

Comment: I am using umbraco dese days , nd using ImageGen with umbraco is quite simple , just load the package and it does all the stuff for you , As the above project was old one , therefore i need to do it manually, i forgot the reference the .dll file which was causing problem , it works perfect now , thnx ..